# Which WordPress scripts need to be executable for a fresh installation?

Tags: htaccess, security, permissions

For security reasons I need to block access to scripts that will not be executed on a fresh WordPress installation.

Example:

- /index.php --> needs to be executable
- /wp-includes/cache.php --> should not be executed (it's included in other files)

Anyone has information on which files are **included** and which actually need to be **executable**?

I want to build a list of valid files that can be executed via .htaccess, like this:

---

**Update:**

This is the .htaccess file I have - my actual question: Is this configuration complete, or do I need to allow more files for a fresh WordPress installation to work properly?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  # ONLY ALLOW THESE SCRIPTS TO EXECUTE:

  # == Login, Signup, Activate
  RewriteRule ^wp-login.php - [L]
  RewriteRule ^wp-activate.php - [L]
  RewriteRule ^wp-signup.php - [L]
  # == All admin scripts and WYSIWYG editor
  RewriteRule ^wp-admin/ - [L]
  RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/wp-tinymce.php - [L]
  # == WP Cron and mail
  RewriteRule ^wp-cron.php - [L]
  RewriteRule ^wp-mail.php - [L]
  # == WP Comments form
  RewriteRule ^wp-comments-post.php - [L]

  # (...) <-- I need to know which other files need to be allowed


  # BLOCK ALL OTHER SCRIPTS
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteRule \.(php.?|pl|cgi)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to WP admin architecture this would be *really* inconvenient list to compile and maintain reliably.

My best educated guess is that many (but possibly not all and not just) of these files would need to require admin bootstrap (`wp-admin/admin.php`) to function.

I ran a quick search on respective directive with following results:

```
C:\server\www\dev\wordpress\src>ack --files-with-matches --literal "require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/admin.php' );"
wp-admin/about.php
wp-admin/admin-header.php
wp-admin/comment.php
wp-admin/credits.php
wp-admin/customize.php
wp-admin/edit-comments.php
wp-admin/edit-tags.php
wp-admin/edit.php
wp-admin/export.php
wp-admin/freedoms.php
wp-admin/import.php
wp-admin/index.php
wp-admin/link-add.php
wp-admin/link-manager.php
wp-admin/link.php
wp-admin/media-new.php
wp-admin/media-upload.php
wp-admin/media.php
wp-admin/ms-admin.php
wp-admin/ms-delete-site.php
wp-admin/ms-edit.php
wp-admin/ms-options.php
wp-admin/ms-sites.php
wp-admin/ms-themes.php
wp-admin/ms-upgrade-network.php
wp-admin/ms-users.php
wp-admin/my-sites.php
wp-admin/nav-menus.php
wp-admin/network/about.php
wp-admin/network/credits.php
wp-admin/network/edit.php
wp-admin/network/freedoms.php
wp-admin/network/index.php
wp-admin/network/plugin-editor.php
wp-admin/network/plugin-install.php
wp-admin/network/plugins.php
wp-admin/network/profile.php
wp-admin/network/settings.php
wp-admin/network/setup.php
wp-admin/network/site-info.php
wp-admin/network/site-new.php
wp-admin/network/site-settings.php
wp-admin/network/site-themes.php
wp-admin/network/site-users.php
wp-admin/network/sites.php
wp-admin/network/theme-editor.php
wp-admin/network/theme-install.php
wp-admin/network/themes.php
wp-admin/network/update-core.php
wp-admin/network/update.php
wp-admin/network/upgrade.php
wp-admin/network/user-edit.php
wp-admin/network/user-new.php
wp-admin/network/users.php
wp-admin/network.php
wp-admin/options-discussion.php
wp-admin/options-general.php
wp-admin/options-media.php
wp-admin/options-permalink.php
wp-admin/options-reading.php
wp-admin/options-writing.php
wp-admin/options.php
wp-admin/plugin-editor.php
wp-admin/plugin-install.php
wp-admin/plugins.php
wp-admin/post-new.php
wp-admin/post.php
wp-admin/press-this.php
wp-admin/revision.php
wp-admin/term.php
wp-admin/theme-editor.php
wp-admin/theme-install.php
wp-admin/themes.php
wp-admin/tools.php
wp-admin/update-core.php
wp-admin/update.php
wp-admin/upload.php
wp-admin/user/about.php
wp-admin/user/credits.php
wp-admin/user/freedoms.php
wp-admin/user/index.php
wp-admin/user/profile.php
wp-admin/user/user-edit.php
wp-admin/user-edit.php
wp-admin/user-new.php
wp-admin/users.php
wp-admin/widgets.php
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! There are so many admin pages that have their own script... Thank you for the feedback and insight!

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress file / folder permissions should be as following.

For Directories: 755

For Files: 644

Except the following:

/wp-content/ 774

/wp-content/themes/ = 755 or 775 (set to allow editing)

/wp-content/plugins/ = 755 Some plugins will complain but if they require write access they will let you know.

/wp-content/uploads/ = 775 check to recursively apply to directories only.  Files in this folder will have different permissions depending on what they are.

**Never use 777**

The information provided on the following pages will help you.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions
http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18352747/1287548
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/08/proper-wordpress-filesystem-permissions-ownerships/

To allow / disallow file execution using .htaccess see the answers provided in the following threads and pages.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8415600/1287548
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11950077/1287548
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-disable-php-execution-in-certain-wordpress-directories/
http://perishablepress.com/stupid-htaccess-tricks/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Vinod :-) This is very useful background information. But what I am looking for is a actual list of php scripts that WordPress needs to run (not so much *how* to set permissions, but *which files* need the execute permissions)

Answer (score 0):

I use this bash command to reset WordPress file permissions quickly and easily, just navigate to your root WP folder and run both:

## directories

`find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

## files

`find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`